# Aws - best practice for long running jobs

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have a lambda function that creates PNG thumbnails from a video when it is uploaded to s3 and puts these png to another s3 bucket. It takes several minutes in lambda, so i am trying to understand the best way to execute It.

Do i have to make a webservice in ec2 and launch It from lambda?
Use aws batch?
Use aws fargate?
Other solutions?

Can you help me please?

Comment: You could consider using [Amazon Elastic Transcoder to generate thumbnails](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/preset-settings.html#preset-settings-thumbnails). Your Lambda function would create the job in Elastic Transcoder, and Elastic Transcoder would store the output in Amazon S3.

Comment: I had seen Elastic Transcoder, but It seems that ET creates thumbnails for every second, i need a thumbnail for every frame, so i need another solution